# How do I use morris.js with Rails 6 and webpacker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm not new to Rails, but I'm new to Rails 6 & webpacker.
I'm trying to integrate morris.js (and raphael.js) into my app.
I've done:

```
 yarn add raphael
 yarn add morris
```

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'raphael' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'morris' %>
```

This is my error:

Webpacker can't find raphael in /Users/jarvis/rails/stuper/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:

1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
   Your manifest contains:

Answer (score 0):

got it working by

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install
```

then i simply added morris-rails and raphael-rails gems